# Distributing identical objects into distinct containers with additional conditions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

We have $122$ identical objects to distribute into 6 distinct containers. Additionally the distribution has to meet the following conditions:

1. Exactly $4$ boxes must contain an **odd** number of objects.
2. There has to be more than $11$ objects in every box.
3. Exactly $3$ boxes must contain at least $26$ objects.

How many ways are there to do that?

I figure this is similiar to the equation type questions ($x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n=r$),which are solved using
$\binom{n + r - 1}{r}$.The problem is including the other conditions in the answer. I've tried using inclusion-exclusion principle, but I don't know how to represent all those sets and their intersections.

Edit:
We have $x_1+x_2+x3+x_4+x_5+x_6=122$.
Because we know that all boxes have more than $11$ items (meaning at least 12), we can replace all $x_i$ with $y_i = x_i - 12$.
Now the equation is $y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4+y_5+y_6=50$.

Additionally, $3$ boxes have at least $26$ items so we can choose $3$ out of $6$ $y$'s and replace them with $z=y-14$.

Assuming $y_1,y_2,y_3$ were replaced we have $z_1+z_2+z_3+y_4+y_5+y_6=8$.
As we know that $4$ out of $6$ numbers are odd we can substitute them with $2x+1$ and the $2$ even numbers can be written as $2x$ (not the same x as before).
So $2x_1+1+2x_2+1+2x_3+1+2x_4+1+2x_5+2x_6=8$
From this we get $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6=2$ with all x>=0.
There are $\binom{6+2-1}{6} = 7$ answers to this equation, so the final answer is $7*\binom{6}{3}*\binom{6}{4}$.
Is this answer correct?

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Note that things simplify somewhat once you have taken the $66=6\times 11$ objects which you know each box must have off the table.  
And simpler again once you have taken the extra $45=15\times 3$ objects that must be in the "high volume" boxes off the table.

Comment: I'll edit in a moment but I think your answer already helped me a little,so thanks for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track, but the answer doesn't seem right. Let me try denovo, and to simplify presentation, I shall try to get rid of the excess "baggage" directly without having to go on changing variables.

The excess baggage is

- $6*12= 72$ for more than $11$ in each box
- $(26-12)\cdot3 =42$ from $\binom63$ boxes
- four $1's$ put in $\binom64$ boxes to ensure odd numbers, keeping others put in as multiples of $2$ for the balance $122-(72+42+4) = 4$

So the simplified problem becomes putting in $2$ non-negative "doubles" in $6$ boxes $\times \binom63\binom64$ yielding
$$\binom{2+6-1}{6-1}\binom63\binom64 $$

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.I believe the first error is an error,because of a misunderstanding.Both the 2 and 3 condition should have been stated in the same way.What I think the exercise meant for the second condition is that in every container there are at least 12 objects.As for the formula,from what I've read on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics) the formula is the one I used.Once again thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: And what do you mean by "26 excess bagagge from C(6,3) boxes"? I thought that the excess baggage from those 3 boxes with at least 26 objects is an additional 26-12=14,as we already accounted for the >=12 in all boxes part.

Comment: I have edited and deleted previous remarks. Your only error is interchanging objects and boxes in the final formula.